# ffmpeg error or success

Tags: unix, ffmpeg

I have a file `sample.aif` on which I want to apply the below filters :

1. Trim sample to a maximum duration of 2 seconds
2. Compression applied with settings : threshold 0.1,ratio=2,attack=5
3. 20 milliseconds fade out at end .

I am running the below ffmpeg command : `ffmpeg -i kick.aif -af atrim=0:120 -af acompressor=threshold=0.1:ratio=2:attack=5 -af afade=d=0.02 kick.ogg 2>error.out`

When I check the return code I see it is 0 however my error. Out file has the below output :

```
cat error.out
ffmpeg version 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, aiff, from 'kick.aif':
  Duration: 00:00:01.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3072 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32be (fl32 / 0x32336C66), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, flt, 3072 kb/s
Output #0, ogg, to 'kick.ogg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libvorbis
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_f32be (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=       6kB time=00:00:01.52 bitrate=  33.9kbits/s
video:0kB audio:2kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 175.053040%
```

I am absolutely new to ffmpeg. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple filters acting on a single input should be specified in the same filterchain, so

```
ffmpeg -i kick.aif -af atrim=0:120,acompressor=threshold=0.1:ratio=2:attack=5,afade=out:st=119.8:d=0.02 kick.ogg 2>error.out
```

Note that `atrim` is keeping the first two *minutes*. The `afade` needs to be set of type `out`, else it will fade-in, and its start time should be set to 20 ms before the end.

Comment: It still says : [AVFilterGraph @ 0x11f96c0] No such filter: 'acompressor' . Can you please throw some light.

Comment: You need ffmpeg v3.0 or later.

Comment: I have downloaded ffmpeg version : 4.0.1 . But the result is still the same . The outfile gets generated but there is always some text which gets redirected to stderr(error.out file in the above example)

Comment: But then how do i do error checking in my script if it always logs to stderr ? i mean if i integrate the results in a Python script for example i have to understand that the command succeeded or failed right.